# My SD card got damaged

Tags: sd-card, data-recovery, encryption, insufficient-memory, water-damage

iam unable to format it not use it. i need an app that will help me recover my data please anyone can share light to this.
Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Interesting - since when does the community bot close questions? Especially as the question does not contain any indicator regarding "internal memory" at all?

Comment: @Robert I suspect, if there are no close votes, but a lot of close flags arrives, then the community bot does the task. But I am not sure - it might worth some digging or a question on the MSE.

Comment: @Robert There is also a change in the question closing system. It is a recent development. If a close review is started (either by a close vote, or by a close flag), then the OP gets a message asking him if he gets the answer in the orig candidate. If he clicks yes, then maybe also Community bot does the closure.

Comment: @Robert someone flagged the question as a duplicate and [the OP agreed with it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/241919).